# How to detect connection loss in a Apache SocketClient on Android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, telnet

I'm making an Android app which opens a telnet connection using Apache's [`TelnetClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.html). For this, I created a `Runnable` which will keep reading in `processInput()` forever. I check with `isConnected()` if the socket is still connected, and if not, I return from the runnable and call `onDisconnected()` on the listeners. However, this last method is never called, even when I turn of Wi-Fi.

I could check the Wi-Fi state, but that does not capture cases when the server hangs up or when the connection is lost for other reasons. How do I detect when the connection is closed?

```
private class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (!client.isConnected()) {
                for (NewRecordListener listener : listeners)
                    listener.onDisconnected();

                try { client.disconnect(); } catch (IOException e) {}

                return;
            }

            try {
                processInput();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I check with isConnected() if the socket is still connected" - you cannot. "Returns:
true if the socket successfuly connected to a server" - does not necessarily mean it will be false as soon as the connection breaks.

Comment: "How do I detect when the connection is closed" - On a non-graceful connection abort there is mostly only the chance to get an IOException while attempting to write.

Comment: You may want to use : [AreYouThere](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.html#sendAYT(long)) periodically.

Comment: Hmm, I am tempted to say that this doc : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#isConnected() is plain wrong. The docs of the Java 6 Socket.isConnected to which this method relays does not say that. Typical behavior of the Java TCP Socket implementations of `isConnected` is that they return true when the Socket has been successfully connected.

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected-- : "Note: Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means this method will return true for a closed socket ... " - That's for Java 8, though. I don't know if they just added that Note or if behavior changed, but I suspect the first.

Comment: @Fildor sorry for the late reply. It took some refactoring, but this works perfectly. Could you write an answer about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I check with isConnected() if the socket is still connected"

You cannot:

> "Returns: true if the socket successfuly connected to a server"

does not necessarily mean it will be false as soon as the connection breaks.

"How do I detect when the connection is closed"

- On a non-graceful connection abort there is mostly only the chance to get an IOException while attempting to write.
- You may want to use : [AreYouThere](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.html#sendAYT(long)) periodically.

---

Sidenote:

I am tempted to say that this [doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#isConnected()):

> Returns true if the client is currently connected to a server.

is plain wrong. The docs of the Java 6 [Socket.isConnected](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html?is-external=true#isConnected()) to which this method delegates to does not say that:

> Returns:
>   true if the socket successfuly connected to a server

Typical behavior of the Java TCP Socket implementations of isConnected is that they return true when the Socket has been successfully connected - *and keep on doing so*.

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected-- :

> Note: Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means this method will return true for a closed socket ... "

That's for Java 8, though. I don't know if they just added that Note or if behavior changed, but I suspect the first.